# Python JSON encoder

Tags: python, json, jquery

I have a dict like this:

```
data = {"data":"http://abc/def"}
```

when I call `json.dumps(data)` I get this:

```
'{"data":"http://abc/def"}'
```

but I want this:

```
'{"data":"http:\/\/abc\/def"}'
```

because I use jquery to parse json but seems like it don't understand unescaped solidus, or is there any way to make jquery understand?

**UPDATE**

For example, here is my json data

```
{"data": ["http://abc.com/aaaaaaaa/bbbbbbbbb/cccccccccc/xyz.mp3"]}
```

Here is my success function

```
function showResult(result) {
            $.each(result.data, function(i, item){
                link = $('<a>').attr('href', item).text(item)
                $("#result").append('<br>')
                $("#result").append(link);
            });
        }
```

The result should be a hyperlink to

```
http://abc.com/aaaaaaaa/bbbbbbbbb/cccccccccc/xyz.mp3
```

But I got a hyperlink to

```
http&#58;&#47;&#47;abc.com&#47;aaaaaaaa&#47;bbbbbbbbb&#47;cccccccccc&#47;xyz.mp3
```

If replace all '/' by '\/', everything is fine

Comment: Can you describe how jquery doesn't understand it or what error you got when you use this json in jquery ?

Comment: Why two backslashes before the forward slash? Surely that means one escaped backslash and one unescaped forward slash?

Comment: Can you show us the jQuery code? I tried `JSON.parse('{"data":"http://abc/def"}')` in my browser's web console and it worked fine.

Comment: @Marcin: I didnt use editor code tag at first

Answer (score 5):

*Normally* you don't escape forward slashes in JSON, but if you are certain this is your problem you can simply do this:

```
s = json.dumps(data)
s = s.replace("/", "\\/")
```

Comment: If you are not using a custom library that messes up the forward slashes, there is something wrong. You should consider locating the bug as it will create more and more problems as your application grows